# How to order array with string value in php

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 'a11',
      'name' => 'A-11', // I want to sort by name
      'state' => 1,
      'cage' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'sub-a-11',
        'name' => 'Cage A',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 'a9',
      'name' => 'A-9', // I want to sort by name
      'state' => 1,
      'cage' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'sub-a-9',
        'nama' => 'Cage A',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => 'a10',
      'name' => 'A-10', // I want to sort by name
      'state' => 1,
      'cage' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'sub-a-10',
        'name' => 'Cage A',
      ),
    ),
)
```

What I want is to re-ordering it by `name` value. So the ordering is become like this:

```
A-9
A-10
A-11
```

I've tried something like code bellow, but still the ordering is not working.

```
$keys = array_column($myData->toArray(), 'name');
array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $myData->toArray());

return $myData;
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: One approach is to use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) in combination with [strnatcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php).

Comment: Use [`SORT_NATURAL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) flag. Example: `array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $array);`